# Flex 4 DataGrid with floating toolbox ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer, toolbox

At my project I've a `DataGrid` component that holds some information and, at the final column I need to put a floating tool box.

The idea is when the user hit on the icon's tool box, it appears above a floating tool box like a menu holding some icons to perform different actions.

So far, I've solved the column's `ItemRenderer` to show the dispatcher tool box icon but to show the upper floating tool box is something that I still can't solve. I've tried to make a custom component ( it's a Canvas that holds a HBox that contains the action's icons ) to hold the tool box's icons and showing it by a Menu control `(mx.control.Menu)` like this:

```
    private function createAndShow():void {
        var myCustomMenu:CustomContextMenu = new CustomContextMenu();
        var myMenu:Menu = Menu.createMenu(this, myCustomMenu, false);
        myMenu.show(btnToolBox.x + 10, btnToolBox.y + 10);
    }
```

But this approach shows a weird container at the left and top of the page instead of show it at the given point i.e. `(btnToolBox.x + 10, btnToolBox.y + 10)`.

So, can anybody help my out with this?

I was searching through the Internet looking for some examples but, I can't found anything that can help me to accomplish this situation so, if anyone knows a way to solve this or at least can point me somehow, any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a long research I found an answer. I created a Custom Component that uses a PopUpAnchor and solution looks like this

```
<s:PopUpAnchor id="hDropDown" x="{btnToolBox.x-options1.width+30}" y="{btnToolBox.y-6}" includeInLayout="false" 
               showEffect="{showEffects}" hideEffect="{hideEffects}">
    <s:BorderContainer minHeight="0" id="options1" mouseDownOutside="{hDropDown.displayPopUp=false}" 
                       cornerRadius="2" borderWeight="1" borderColor="gray" backgroundColor="black">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout gap="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5" />
        </s:layout>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:PopUpAnchor>
```